# Angular material 2 checkboxes on mat table hiding on hover for large records

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table with selectable rows that contains 300(+) records. Following [this](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection) tutorial, I created this table.

The component containing this table is a child component. Upon rendering of the table, when I scroll and hover over the checkboxes, they are hiding and showing something like this.

[image]

Not sure what is happening here. I tried with a normal component that's not a child component and the table's working just fine. Can anyone please suggest a workaround. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: This component is part of a tab-group.**

**app.component.ts**

```
displayColumns = ['select', 'position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'icon'];
dataSources = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
selections = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);

/** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
isAllSelected() {
 const numSelected = this.selections.selected.length;
 const numRows = this.dataSources.data.length;
 return numSelected === numRows;
}

/** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
masterToggles() {
  this.isAllSelected() ?
  this.selections.clear() :
  this.dataSources.data.forEach(row => this.selections.select(row));
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- Checkbox Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggles() : null"
                  [checked]="selections.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                  [indeterminate]="selections.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                  (change)="$event ? selections.toggle(row) : null"
                  [checked]="selections.isSelected(row)">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Symbol Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!--icon-->
<ng-container matColumnDef="icon">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ICON </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <mat-icon matTooltip="Some Tootip Text">info
    </mat-icon>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns;"
         (click)="selections.toggle(row)">
</mat-row>
```

**Workaround:**

Instead of using the `mat-checkbox` of Angular Material, I rather used the basic HTML element `input type="checkbox"` and this solved my problem.

I believe the issue might have been caused due to some material css override and using the HTML input, the problem got resolved.

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can help you ?

Comment: @Nico_, I have added my code for reference.